# Condition1 OR Condition2

Tags: if-statement, vb6

I want to do something like this:

```
strCurrentName = rstAux.Fields("Name")
strCurrentMat = rstAux.Fields("ID")

    Dim rstAux                      As Recordset
    Dim rstReal                     As Recordset
    Dim strCurrentName              As String
    Dim strCurrentMat               As String

    Set rstAux = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rstReal = New ADODB.Recordset

    If( (strCurrentName = rstReal.Fields("Name")) OR (strCurrentMat = rstReal.Fields("ID")) Then  
            'codeee
    End If
```

Is it possible on VB6?

I tried different ways to do so, but I always get error like:
**Variables uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic**

Ok, I get what the message means, but I'd like to know if there is a way to do so.

Comment: Of course there is a way to do so. VB6 supports boolean logic, like every other programming language in the world. `uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic` is the source of the problem, and for an answer to *that* you need to tell what what these variables are and where they come from. Show your actual code and add some explanation.

Comment: OR is certainly possible in VB6.  Your statement is mostly correct, I would skip the outermost parenteses, but otherwise it looks OK.  I think the error is referring to something else than the OR part - how do your conditions look like?

Comment: @GTG take a look at the update please.

Comment: You still have not explained what `rstReal` is and what datatype `.Fields()` returns. I can only suspect it's a RecordSet of some sort (ADO? DAO?), but as a rule: if you want useful answers, don't make people guess.

Comment: @Tomalak sorry about that, updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, all your variables are strings, check out if the return of the `rstReal.("field") are also strings, if not, make a conversion. I believe name is string, so check the "ID".

```
If(strCurrentName = rstReal.Fields("Name") OR (strCurrentMat = CString(rst.Fields("ID")) Then
     'code code
End If
```

Comment: I'm so dumb u.u
Worked ! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Dim rstAux                      As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rstReal                     As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strCurrentName              As String
Dim strCurrentMat               As String

If strCurrentName = rstReal.Fields("Name").Value Or _
   strCurrentMat = rstReal.Fields("ID").Value Then
    'codeee
End If
```

But since `.Value` is the default property of a `Field` object, it should have worked with your version as well.

Comment: Actually the `rstReal.Fields("ID") was an `Integer` and I had to convert it to string... =s I'm so dumb x.x

Comment: Ah you are right. Comparing a String to an Integer triggers a type mismatch error.